# Is there any bad impact to using set name 'utf8' by default in selection?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, set, names

Is there any bad impact to using `set name 'utf8'` by default in SQL select query?

Comment: Don't think y down vote after 4years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collation and the SET name may not have that vast impact on your project, but it doesn't mean that you shouldn't follow a standard collation method for the whole database. I prefer if you could go for a standard collation values, it would be less trouble for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is no bad impact that I know of, but will be rather more tolerant with the input in terms of what is inputted, which might be a bad thing, but of what I know, it is a good thing.